# Closing a QMessageBox via automated tests causes "Cannot set parent" warning and eventual crash

Tags: qt, pyqt, robotframework, pyqt6

I have a QtPy6 application that creates QMessageBox instances anonymously, **only from the main thread**:

```py
msg = QMessageBox.critical(None, "Invalid name!", "Your output name can only be alphanumeric!")
```

I also have an automation test suite that must close opened QMessageBoxes when `start_gui_repack()` is called, which is done by scheduling a call to `close_active_modals()` as follows (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370957/how-can-i-access-handle-qmessagebox-instances-using-qtest-in-pyqt) for an explanation):

```py
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class clientGUILib():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = client.MyMainWindow() 
        self.gui.show()
        self.repackPanel = self.gui.repackFilePanel
        
    def close_active_modals(self):
        while isinstance(QApplication.activeWindow(), QMessageBox):
            win: QMessageBox = QApplication.activeWindow()
            closeBtn = win.defaultButton()
            QTest.mouseClick(closeBtn, Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)
            QApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def start_gui_repack(self, delay_time=1):
        threading.Timer(delay_time, self.close_active_modals).start()
        QTest.mouseClick(self.repackPanel.repackButton, Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton)
        QApplication.processEvents()
```

Any test that uses these methods prints the following warnings to console:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

I'm not sure how to trace what object this warning is coming from.
Rarely, either of these warnings will also appear; again, I'm not sure what in my code could be causing them or if they are relevant at all.

```
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
```

In my test suite, each test individually runs, triggering a repack operation which creates up to 3 message boxes. These message boxes all get closed by the `close_active_modals()` method, but leave behind more copies of the warning each time. The application eventually crashes, which seems to be related to how many of these warnings are printed; the amount of tests completed is always inconsistent - for example (//comments added by me):

```
Repack T0 And Delete Files And Folders                                ..
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
Repack T0 And Delete Files And Folders                                | PASS |
//1 message box expected
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Repack T12 Without Deletion                                           ...
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
Repack T12 Without Deletion                                           | PASS |
//1 message box expected
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Repack T12 And Delete Files                                           ...
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
//3 message boxes expected, crashes here
```

As my message boxes are created using the static functions method, I can't use the `msg.close()` function without code changes. However, I did try converting some of my code to use the property-based method but got the same behaviour.

I'm not sure if this has to do with the way my test suite is set up; `clientGuiLib.py` is set as a library import for a RobotFramework test file and I'm assuming the global-scoped `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` is enough to run the application properly; I'm not familiar enough with RobotFramework to know exactly how this is handled.

Unrelated questions regarding the same warning all seem to suggest that interacting with the GUI from a non-GUI thread isn't a good idea. However, my method of [closing QMessageBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370957/how-can-i-access-handle-qmessagebox-instances-using-qtest-in-pyqt) seems to be the only way to do it, as the main thread is blocked while a message box is open. I'm not sure if using QTest methods is considered "interacting with the GUI from an outside thread".

I can't figure out how to avoid the application crashing when all tests are run sequentially, and have no idea why it's so inconsistent or what precisely is causing it. I wasn't able to find a way to turn on a verbose logging mode for PyQt6 that would help me trace where the warning is coming from exactly either. I'm looking for first and foremost a solution to the crash, but if I haven't provided enough information, a solution to the `QObject::setParent` warning or at least a way to trace it would be super appreciated.

Comment: Ui elements are not thread safe, and shall **never** be accessed by external threads. Doing it isn't just "not a good idea", it's completely wrong. Use QTimer, which should be able to trigger even with the time.sleep as long as you're constantly processing events (but you should probably decrease the sleep time to a few cents, half a second is too much and quite pointless.

Comment: @musicamante This worked, thank you! I just had to replace the threading timer with `QTimer.singleShot(delay_time, self.close_active_modals)`. If you want you can post that as an answer and I can mark it as correct.